# Creative Soundblaster play! 2

Tags: soundcard

In this [answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2313677), I have found Creative Sound blaster play! 2 USB Sound card is supported: there is a code for it. But I do not understand how to use this code to enable the sound card.

---

Re: Creative Soundblaster play! 2 USB Sound card is supported?

Hey.

Yes, it is. Out of the box:

Code:

```
[230043.324099] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[230043.652736] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[230044.008096] input: Creative Technology Ltd Sound Blaster Play! 2 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.3/0003:041E:323D.0005/input/input24
[230044.059778] hid-generic 0003:041E:323D.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw4: USB HID v1.00 Device [Creative Technology Ltd Sound Blaster Play! 2] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input3
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question uses a [code] block for formatting text, but the text you see is system log output for the plug-and-play system, meaning it should work automatically when you plug it in. No need to "write code".